# How to Dynamically Pivot a table with join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, KeyIndexes and IndexTypes.

[image]

[image]

For all ImageFileID present in the first table I want the result in single row like below-

[image]

Here is the SQL fiddle for above- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c9a2/2/0

How to get it done using PIVOT or anything in SQL Server?

Comment: Please provide https://dbfiddle.uk sample data. It will be much easier than images. Nice avatar - old style SO with 6 pieces while new one has only 5 :)

Comment: Add some some sample data and expected output people don't expect screen shots

Comment: I have edited the question and provided a Fiddle. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts I created following dynamic pivot query which is working fine for above mentioned problem:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[pGetQAReleaseRejectRec]
@ImageFileID as int=null
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)    

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([FieldName]) 
                    FROM KeyIndexes k join 
IndexTypes i on k.IndexTypeID=i.IndexTypeID
where ImageFileID=@ImageFileID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @query='
select * from
(
  select ImageFileID,k.KeyIndexValue,i.FieldName from KeyIndexes k join 
IndexTypes i on k.IndexTypeID=i.IndexTypeID 
where ImageFileID= '+CONVERT(varchar, @ImageFileID)+'
) s
PIVOT
(
    max(KeyIndexValue)
    FOR [FieldName] IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pvt'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without PIVOT.

```
SELECT
    ImageFileID,
    PolicyNumber = MAX(CASE WHEN IndexTypeID=1 THEN KeyIndexValue ELSE NULL END)
    ...
FROM
    KeyIndexes
GROUP BY
    ImageFileID
```

Comment: If PolicyNumber is not available for another record in second table then it will throw error.